# Save version of file to drive, when the drive changes from computer to computer

Tags: vba, directory, export-to-csv

I made a macro to export my xlsm file into a csv file. It works great on one computer where the directory of the server is "I" but on another computer with the same server saved to directory "T" it fails. Is there a solution to this multi-directory/multi-computer problem? The trimmed code is attached with the directory line pointed out.

```
Sub ExportAsCSV()
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult, Dir As String, LastRow As Long, _
    Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date, CSVFileName As String
' *********************************************************
' Directory String <---------------- The Issue
    Dir = "I:\2017\CVS" ' Could be "I:\", could be "T:\" ...
' *********************************************************
' Creating the Name of the CSV File using the _
' first and last date in column C (C1 is a header)
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Date1 = Range("C2").Value
    Date2 = Cells(LastRow, "C")
    If Date1 < Date2 Then
        CSVFileName = "FILE." & Format(Date1, "mm.dd.yy") & _
        "-" & Format(Date2, "mm.dd.yy") & ".csv"
    ElseIf Date1 > Date2 Then
        CSVFileName = "FILE." & Format(Date2, "mm.dd.yy") & _
        "-" & Format(Date1, "mm.dd.yy") & ".csv"
    Else
        CSVFileName = "FILE." & Format(Date1, "mm.dd.yy") & ".csv"
    End If

' Double Check User wants to make a sheet Response
    Answer = MsgBox("Clicking 'Yes' will create a CSV file named " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "     " & CSVFileName & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "into " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "     " & Dir & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "It will overwrite any CSV with an identical name." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Is this what you want to do?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

'Act based on the Response
    If Answer = vbYes Then
        ' Ready all cells for csv creation
    Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        ws.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=Dir & "\" & CSVFileName, _
            FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        MsgBox ("Created the csv file:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        Dir & "\" & CSVFileName)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Did not create the csv file.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably not the problem, but `Dir` being a function in the `VBA.FileSystem` standard library module, your local variable `Dir` is hiding it. Not a good idea.

Comment: Can you not use UNC paths instead of mapped network drives?

Comment: I very well may be able to but I don't know enough about it. I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a UNC path instead of a mapped network drive.

```
Dir = "\\ServerName\SomeFolder\2017\CVS"
```

If you don't know what server/folder the network drive is pointing to, ask your network administrator.

---

#### Side note

You shouldn't name things in ways that hide/shadow identifiers that already exist in global namespace: `Dir` is actually a function in the `VBA.FileSystem` module; by declaring a `Dir` local variable, you make the name potentially ambiguous to the reader (although the compiler doesn't care).

Comment: Thank you, will alter the Dir name and test now.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Under my Computer on computer 1, I see (edited so nonsensitive):   Local Disck (C:) ; AAA (\\name01) (I:) ; BBB(\\name01) (J:) ; CCC (\\name01) (K:) . On computer 2 I see: Local Disck (C:) ; AAA (\\name01) (T:) ; BBB (\\name01) (U:) ; CCC (\\name01) (V:) ... where I am interested in AAA(\\name01) (I:) and AAA(\\name01) (T:) which are the same server. How would I use UNC in this case?

Comment: Type `\\name01` in the Windows Explorer address bar. Each drive is pointing to a specific network share at that location: that's what you use to build your UNC path.

Comment: There's the trick. However, my Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheets1") has become an issue... It returns "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" ... anything strike you as an obvious issue?

Comment: That means there's no sheet labelled `Sheets1` in the active workbook. Likely it's actually labelled `Sheet1`, but that's what you have in the question - so if a user re-labelled "Sheet1" to "MyStuff" then your code breaks. Don't pull worksheets by their label/name, and don't work off the `ActiveWorkbook` either. If the sheet is in `ThisWorkbook` then give it a *code name* identifier (the `(Name)` property in the properties toolwindow /F4) and use that in code, e.g. `Sheet1.Copy`.

Comment: You've solved my original question so I marked this as answered. As of now I am just debugging code and I appreciate your advice. I will look into tutorials in how to do as you suggest. Best